# PHP/regex - Find (and replace) relative url with absolute (regardless of href existence)

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a small PHP project, and I need to replace every relative url found in a string with an absolute version of it. The issue is, I've found plenty of answers to this question, but all of them require the url be prefixed by an href.
A simple example of what I need converted is as follows:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Feed for question &#39;preg_replace to change url from relative to absolute&#39;" href="/feeds/question/19373024">
        <meta name="twitter:app:country" content="US" />
        <meta name="twitter:app:name:iphone" content="Stack Exchange iOS" />
        <meta name="twitter:app:id:iphone" content="871299723" />
        <meta name="twitter:app:url:iphone" content="se-zaphod://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373024/preg-replace-to-change-url-from-relative-to-absolute" />
```

and in this case, that should show up (after being converted) as:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Feed for question &#39;preg_replace to change url from relative to absolute&#39;" href="http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/19373024">
        <meta name="twitter:app:country" content="US" />
        <meta name="twitter:app:name:iphone" content="Stack Exchange iOS" />
        <meta name="twitter:app:id:iphone" content="871299723" />
        <meta name="twitter:app:url:iphone" content="se-zaphod://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373024/preg-replace-to-change-url-from-relative-to-absolute" />
```

Comment: your example also has "href"

Comment: how do you want to differentiate between a relative link and something like  `se-zaphod://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373024/pr...`?

Comment: @Robert, You're right, let me fix that.

Comment: @syck, I don't know how I would, which is an issue.

Comment: Actually, it looks like I don't need it to not require an href. I feel stupid now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = '/\"\/feeds\/question/';
$subject = "href='/feeds/question/19373024'>";
$replacement = "http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
```

Edit: You can set your regex pattern with $pattern in preg_replace.
Here I did this: https://regex101.com/r/xB0dY5/1

Then in $subject I loaded a string with "feeds/questions" in it.
in $replacement the string which should replace the regex selected stuff.

You should regex with "(quote)("/feeds...) otherwise it would select also feeds/questions the second link.

Comment: Nice block of code. Try and insert some words here and there to help the asker understand what you did.